# Wrong cuFFT 2D Convolution results with non square matrix

Tags: c++, image-processing, cuda, fft, convolution

I'm trying to perform a 2D convolution using the "FFT + point_wise_product + iFFT" aproach. Using NxN matrices the method goes well, however, with **non square matrices** the results are not correct. I've read the whole cuFFT documentation looking for any note about the behavior with this kind of matrices, tested in-place and out-place FFT, but I'm forgetting something.

I've tested the same algorithm with the same matrices in MATLAB and everthing is correct.
I show you a very simplified code, with a very basic filter for clarity, its output, and the expected output. What am I doing wrong?
I've also read other related questions/answers but none of them solve the problem. Thank you very much in advance.

```
const int W = 5;
const int H = 4;

//Signal, with just one value, for simplicity.
float A[H][W] = {{0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0}};

//Central element of the kernel in the (0,0) position of the array.
float B[H][W] = {{0.5, 0.1,  0,    0,  0.2},
        {0  ,  0  ,  0,    0,  0},
        {0  ,  0  ,  0,    0,  0},
        {0  ,  0  ,  0,    0,  0}};


cufftReal* d_inA, *d_inB;
cufftComplex* d_outA, *d_outB;

size_t real_size = W * H * sizeof(cufftReal);
size_t complex_size = W * (H/2+1) * sizeof(cufftComplex);

cudaMalloc((void**)&d_inA, real_size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_inB, real_size);

cudaMalloc((void**)&d_outA, complex_size);
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_outB, complex_size);

cudaMemset(d_inA,0,real_size);
cudaMemset(d_inB,0,real_size);

cudaMemcpy(d_inA, A, real_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_inB, B, real_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


cufftHandle fwplanA, fwplanB, bwplan;
cufftPlan2d(&fwplanA, W, H, CUFFT_R2C);
cufftPlan2d(&fwplanB, W, H, CUFFT_R2C);
cufftPlan2d(&bwplan, W, H, CUFFT_C2R);

cufftSetCompatibilityMode(fwplanA,CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE);
cufftSetCompatibilityMode(fwplanB,CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE);
cufftSetCompatibilityMode(bwplan,CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE);   

cufftExecR2C(fwplanA, d_inA, d_outA);
cufftExecR2C(fwplanB, d_inB, d_outB);

int blocksx = ceil((W*(H/2+1 )) / 256.0f);
dim3 threads(256);
dim3 grid(blocksx);
// One complex product for each thread, scaled by the inverse of the
// number of elements involved in the FFT
pointwise_product<<<grid, threads>>>(d_outA, d_outB, (W*(H/2+1)), 1.0f/(W*H));

cufftExecC2R(bwplan, d_outA, d_inA);


cufftReal* result = new cufftReal[W*2*(H/2+1)];
cudaMemcpy(result, d_inA, real_size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

// Print result...
// Free memory...
```

Output. Note the displaced value

```
-0.0  0.0   -0.0   -0.0   0.0   
0.0   0.5    0.1    0.0   -0.0  
0.2   0.0    0.0   -0.0   -0.0  
-0.0  0.0   -0.0   -0.0   -0.0
```

Expected output (MATLAB)

```
0         0         0         0         0
0.2000    0.5000    0.1000    0.0000    0.0000
0         0         0         0         0
0         0         0         0         0
```

Related Doc:
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_2/sdk/website/projects/convolutionFFT2D/doc/convolutionFFT2D.pdf

Comment: Are you exchanging rows with columns in your cufft plan? The prototype is `cufftPlan2d(cufftHandle *plan, int nx, int ny, cufftType type)` where `nx` is the number of rows and `ny` is the number of columns, so it should be `cufftPlan2d(&fwplanA, H, W, CUFFT_R2C);` and not `cufftPlan2d(&fwplanA, W, H, CUFFT_R2C);`.

Comment: That was the error... I can't believe I didn't see it before. I reviewed the cufft documentation and say nx=rows, ny=columns...
Thank you very much!

Comment: I have added an answer to your question to remove this post from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are exchanging rows with columns in your cufft plan.

The relevant prototype is

```
 cufftPlan2d(cufftHandle *plan, int nx, int ny, cufftType type)
```

where `nx` is the number of rows and `ny` is the number of columns, so it should be

```
 cufftPlan2d(&fwplanA, H, W, CUFFT_R2C);
```

and not

```
 cufftPlan2d(&fwplanA, W, H, CUFFT_R2C);
```

Comment: What kind of half-ass, masochistic, self-righteous programmer decided that X indicates height and Y indicates width? So frustrating... Hours lost.